# Android: Is there any exceptions that would occur?

Tags: android, exception

I have used three check boxes, When button is clicked if all the three check boxes are checked it goes to **if** condition  or else it goes to **else** condition (i.e if one or two or no check box is checked) , I just wanted to know whether any exception occurs or not.
CheckBox.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheckBox extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkbox);
        Button btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
         android.widget.CheckBox chk1 =(android.widget.CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
         android.widget.CheckBox chk2 =(android.widget.CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk2);
         android.widget.CheckBox chk3 =(android.widget.CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk3);
         if (chk1.isChecked()==true&&chk2.isChecked()==true&&chk3.isChecked()==true) {

            txt.setText("selected locations are"+chk1.getText().toString()+","+chk2.getText().toString()+","+chk3.getText().toString());

        }
         else{
            txt.setText("select all locations");
         }

    }


}
```

Comment: If it compiles there's no exceptions you have to catch.  That doesn't mean one won't happen, but if it does that's a bug you need to fix, not something to catch and ignore.  And you tell that by running it and checking.

Comment: no exceptions occurred while running

Comment: That kind of naming might lead to exception some time. If you omit `android.widget` before `CheckBox`, you might not notice what type your checkbox is. Yes, CheckBox extends either view or activity, in your case, which would result in compile error, if types were not matched, but if you extend View and have duplicate class names, it may result in RuntimeException.

Comment: If this is the full code, I can say there won't be any run-time exceptions. However, some namings can be problematic as stated by Marius. Also, some syntax are redundant (e.g. if a function returns boolean and you want to use in `if-block`, you don't need to compare to boolean value, just write `chk1.isChecked() && ...`). Well, since I think this code is actually working, I may suggest to post this in [codereview.SE] to get feedback on coding standard itself.